# HelloWorld Deployment with QtQuick 2.0 in Windows 7 and XP

Tags: visual-c++, deployment, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I've been struggling to get my application deployed properly for several weeks now (it's a hobby), and I just don't know what else to try.

I started a new project in Qt Creator (2.6.1), by selecting Applications -> Qt Quick 2 Application (Built-in Elements). I tweaked the QML to make the background blue and text red:

#### main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    width: 360
    height: 360
    color: "blue" // Added!
    Text {
        text: qsTr("Hello World")
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        color: "red" // Added!
    }
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            Qt.quit();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using Qt 5.0.1 and the x86 MSVC 2010 compiler. I built the Release version and it ran fine in QtCreator. If you need more compiler specifics, I'll post them.

To deploy, I created a new folder on my desktop called `HelloWorld/` and copied **everything** from `H:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\msvc2010\bin\*` and `H:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\msvc2010\plugins\*` and 'H:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\msvc2010\qml* into it, along with the Release HelloWorld.exe executable.

Overkill? Yes. But I'm desperate.

When I run HelloWorld/HelloWorld.exe in Windows 7 64-bit, the application runs fine. But when I copy this HelloWorld/ folder over into a virtual machine running Windows XP 32-bit, it shows a properly-sized window, but with nothing in it (white, with no text). When clicking in the center of the window, the window closes as it should.

So I loaded the executable in Dependency Walker, but nothing looked out of the ordinary (IESHIMS.DLL and WER.DLL were of course missing). I ran Start Profile, and got a slew of red errors:

> GetProcAddress(0x7C800000 [KERNEL32.DLL], "FlsAlloc") called from "MSVCR100.DLL" at address 0x78ABBA3B and returned NULL. Error: The specified procedure could not be found (127).
>
> GetProcAddress(0x7C800000 [KERNEL32.DLL], "FlsGetValue") called from "MSVCR100.DLL" at address 0x78ABBA48 and returned NULL. Error: The specified procedure could not be found (127).
>
> GetProcAddress(0x7C800000 [KERNEL32.DLL], "FlsSetValue") called from "MSVCR100.DLL" at address 0x78ABBA55 and returned NULL. Error: The specified procedure could not be found (127).
>
> GetProcAddress(0x7C800000 [KERNEL32.DLL], "FlsFree") called from "MSVCR100.DLL" at address 0x78ABBA62 and returned NULL. Error: The specified procedure could not be found (127).
>
> LoadLibraryExW("C:\documents and settings\owner\desktop\helloworld\platforms\qminimald.pdb", 0x00000000, DONT_RESOLVE_DLL_REFERENCES) returned NULL. Error: %1 is not a valid Win32 application (193).
>
> LoadLibraryExW("C:\documents and settings\owner\desktop\helloworld\platforms\qwindowsd.pdb", 0x00000000, DONT_RESOLVE_DLL_REFERENCES) returned NULL. Error: %1 is not a valid Win32 application (193).
>
> GetProcAddress(0x7E410000 [USER32.DLL], "UpdateLayeredWindowIndirect") called from "QWINDOWS.DLL" at address 0x013A8749 and returned NULL. Error: The specified procedure could not be found (127).
>
> GetProcAddress(0x7C9C0000 [SHELL32.DLL], "SHCreateItemFromParsingName") called from "QWINDOWS.DLL" at address 0x013A8997 and returned NULL. Error: The specified procedure could not be found (127).
>
> GetProcAddress(0x7C9C0000 [SHELL32.DLL], "SHGetStockIconInfo") called from "QWINDOWS.DLL" at address 0x013A89C9 and returned NULL. Error: The specified procedure could not be found (127).
>
> GetProcAddress(0x7C800000 [KERNEL32.DLL], "GetTickCount64") called from "QT5CORE.DLL" at address 0x670726A7 and returned NULL. Error: The specified procedure could not be found (127).
>
> GetProcAddress(0x755C0000 [MSCTFIME.IME], "ImeGetImeMenuItems") called from "IMM32.DLL" at address 0x76397354 and returned NULL. Error: The specified procedure could not be found (127).
>
> GetProcAddress(0x4FDD0000 [D3D9.DLL], "Direct3DCreate9Ex") called from "LIBEGL.DLL" at address 0x01487198 and returned NULL. Error: The specified procedure could not be found (127).

I also tried to run a debug version, but I only have the 64-bit versions of the MSVC100 dll's, so I can't copy them to the XP machine (I can only run the 32-bit redistributable). I don't know what other tools I can use to try to solve my problem.

I know I must be doing something stupid, but I really can't find anything on the internet to help. It's really frustrating to spend so much time developing a Qt application, and then get stuck trying to deploy it.

I should note that the program runs just fine in a Windows 7 32-bit virtual machine (after MSVC2012 redistributable has been installed).

The application I'm *really* interested in running, runs really strangely in Windows XP. When I first run it, the window sizes properly and a couple text strings show up. But none of the Rectangle{} elements are displayed. I left the app running for a few minutes as I made myself some coffee, and when I returned to my computer, the window was blinking random shapes and text, to the beat of the text cursor! What the heck is that?! It looked like a basic math function was screwed up, so parts of the interface were being displayed at improper sizes and positions. I even saw the real interface show up for one blink of the mouse cursor (and yes, the random shapes appear and disappear to the beat of the mouse cursor).

On a whim, I tried using the application (clicking where I **know** a text box exists), to populate one of the lists, and it worked! The application is running completely fine, except for the graphics. I know Qt 5.0 reworked some of the OpenGL handling, right? Could this be a bug, or maybe a library I haven't installed?

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem when deploying quick 2.0 application on Windows XP builded by Qt 5.1 rc1 with ANGLE; It's seems to be ANGLE problem, on http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt-5-on-Windows-ANGLE-and-OpenGL is recommended to use OPENGL for XP, also Qt 5.1 with OPENGL works for me on Windows XP

Answer (score 0):

1. Install [Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555)
   on client machine (windows xp).
2. Use release build, not debug build, You seems to be using Debug
   version.
3. Don't use OpenGL(Most of XP Users may note have updated OpenGL
   version, otherwise‍ you may have to force them to upgrade it.)

**Update**
Use OpenGL for Windows XP. User have to install or upgrade their OpenGL drivers. [Read this](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt-5-on-Windows-ANGLE-and-OpenGL).

Answer (score -1):

Try using the MinGW version instead of the VC++ one. It's likely that there are layers and layers of .Net stuff preventing you from running on XP. XP came out before 90% of the current .Net stuff existed which is why it wont work as it's not installed.

Just a guess but its worth a shot.

Comment: See my EDIT AGAIN section in my original post. I think it's likely more related to a graphics problem than a compiler problem. The application **does** run, it just doesn't show the graphics properly.